# PHP class that extends ArrayObject failing instanceof ArrayObject

Tags: php

Fairly new to PHP..

I've got a class that extends ArrayObject, this class then gets passed to function elsewhere which runs a check to see if the class is of type ArrayObject or Array, forgive the terminology.

Here's the class in question:

```
use ArrayObject;
use ArrayAccess;

class Parser extends ArrayObject implements ArrayAccess
{
     public $data = [];

     //Custom functions & ArrayAccess interface functions all present below..
}
```

So in some other class

```
class SomeClass 
{
   public function __construct()
   {
       $this->expectingArrayObjectType = new Parser();

       $this->config($this->expectingArrayObjectType);
   }

   private function config($name, $value = null)
   {
        if($name instanceof ArrayObject || is_array($name)) {
             //This never gets hit..    
        }
   }
}
```

I'm actually getting passed the problem by changing

```
$this->config($this->expectingArrayObjectType);
```

To this

```
$this->config($this->expectingArrayObjectType->data);
```

Which is perfectly understandable (to my knowledge), it's just confusing me as I'm reverse-engineering a friends code and they are passing in the Parser object and it's hitting the check for being of type ArrayObject, and mine is not lol.

Anyone able to share any insight?

Cheers

Comment: Actually you have syntax error at `public $data = [];` line. It should be `public $data = array();`

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve by extending ArrayObject and introducing an `public $data` array?

Comment: @TigranTokmajyan Actually that is syntactically correct as of PHP 5.4+